# LMR64010 using externaly adjustable feedback voltage

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, boost, step-up

I am using a basic application circuit for [LMR64010](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr64010.pdf). The output voltage is adjustable by changing resistor R2 (R1 is a fixed value of 13.3 kΩ).

I would like to know how to modify this basic circuit to control the output voltage with an external voltage, instead of changing resistor R2. For this task I would like to use a 0-3.3 V voltage signal (microcontroller PWM/DAC output).

Comment: I'm not sure if this approach is feasible, and interested if anyone can answer this. But have you considered a digital potentiometer?

Comment: As I understand resistors R1 and R2 works as voltage divider and provides desired voltage level to FB pin of this IC. So I think it should be possible to replace this part of voltage divider using external voltage source, such as PWM or DAC signal from microcontroller. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a digital pot.  Just introduce a current into the summing node (FB pin) which offsets the apparent reading.  If the divider's Thevenin resistance is say 1kΩ, then injecting 1mA offsets it by 1V.  If that's 1mA downward (acting to pull down the node voltage), the buck output will increase such that the feedback rises by 1V to compensate; so, the output rises by 1V ÷ (divider gain).

> I have an example using LMR62421: 
> [image: Adjustable buck converter] 
> Could I use this circuit for LMR64010?

Well, not with R133 so small, heh, but if that was for a constant-current circuit, maybe supplying a stack of LEDs, that would explain that, and indeed the voltage on a shunt resistor can be regulated in the same way.  In any case, note that R131 constitutes the usual feedback divider, but with a gain of 1: there is an implied resistor from FB to GND, not shown because its value is infinite.  We can insert this resistor to adjust gain as desired.  And remove R133 and shift R131 to Vout for a constant-voltage output.

Note that the signal coming in from the left can be PWM, in which case R134+R135, C50 serve to filter it.  This also limits the output bandwidth / slew rate, of course.  If a DAC is used (no PWM), the capacitor can be omitted and the resistors can be simplified to their series equivalent.

Comment: As I understand, I have to connect R131 between FB and Vout, then remove R133. Resistors R134, R135 and R132 can be kept as connected in this circuit. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @Tom And add a resistor FB to GND. R131 becomes the top divider or R1 in the application circuit, and you still need an R2 to reach higher output voltages.